# How to change the order of opening windows in cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I had a mutil windows cocoa porject. and now I want to change the order of opening windows , How to do it ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just open the windows programmatically instead of allowing it to happen automatically. So in interface builder uncheck "visible at launch" for every window. Then in your code use [myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self] to show a window.